# Lost connection to MySQL server at 'waiting for initial communication packet'

Tags: mysql

I have seen many stack overflows questions and some blogs tried workarounds, but nothings helped - hence re-posting the question with more details.

I am seeing the weird behaviour with MySQL and Python application, details are as follows:

1) My application works perfectly fine with MySQL (tried and tested on many platforms) but on this particular machine it fails to connect to MySQL.

**structure of application is :**

```
   Windows service -> parent process -> Mysql(child process)
```

and when application tries to connect to MySQL it get this error:

```
ERROR 2013 , Lost connection to MySQL server at 'waiting for initial communication packet' - system error 0
```

**I tried:**

```
- connect_timeout=300
- skip-name-resolve=0
- firewall is OFF
- use 17.0.0.1, localhost , IP of machine to connect to but it still fails with same error.
```

2) Now the weird thing is -

If I manually follow all the steps which application does, It works perfectly fine, details are follows:
a) Start MySQL with same command (which application uses) with administrator privileges

```
mysql --default-file = xxx --basedir =xxx
```

b) Connect with same credentials ( `-u root -P 6075 -h 127.0.0.1`) and 
 It works perfectly fine, I double checked all the steps which application does, there is no difference between manually steps and application code.

AM I missing something here ? Any suggestions ?

```
MySQL version : 5.5.35
Python : 2.7
Base OS : Windows 2012 R2
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 6):

**Found a reason - answering my question:**

When I used to run MySQL from my application - it was running under system user  privileges - so it used to pick "**C:\WINDOWS\TEMP**" as a temp directory- this directory was messed up - has lot of unnecessary files .. and MySQL was stuck while processing files under this directory...

But when I ran it manually under My administrator account it was using his temp directory... **C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Temp** and everything was working like magic...

To fix this permanently I changed tmp directory through MySQL conf file and now My Application runs like the Wind.... :)

```
[mysqld]
tmpdir = 'PATH_TO_THE_DIRECTORY'
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this same error trying to set up a SQL Server Linked Server

```
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "DBLINKED".
OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "DBLINKED" returned message "[MySQL][ODBC 8.0(w) Driver]Lost connection to MySQL server at 'waiting for initial communication packet', system error: 10060". (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7303)
```

You mentioned it in your initial question - the Connection Timeout was the issue for me.

The default is 0 - raised it to 300. I thought default of 0 would mean no timeout, but it's obviously something reasonably short, and I was trying to connect to a remote database on a slow internet connection. A lot of other question and answers out there relate to connecting within the same machine, so this error isn't reported much.